# make variables in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

i have some array like this

```
$post_array = array("title","content","price","dt","cat");
```

i want to make variable for all of them like this :

```
$title = $_GET['title'];
$content = $_GET['content'];
```

is that possible?

Comment: `extract(array_intersect_key(array_flip($post_array), $_GET))`

Answer (score 2):

You can do simply using `extract`.

```
extract($_GET);
```

See [doc](http://php.net/extract).

If you want to make sure all of them exist, you can use a for loop this way:

```
foreach($post_array as $input) {
    $$input = $_GET[$input];
}
```

This works because in php if say `$var` is `'title'`, `$$var` refers to the variable `$title`.

Comment: @sebcap26: Right. Hence, the [warning](http://php.net/extract#refsect1-function.extract-notes) in doc.